# Any (old?) Pi with non-micro SD card?

Tags: sd-card

Is there or were there ever any Raspberry Pi with "full sized" (non-micro) SD card?

I've been reading a number of articles on SD cards issues for RPi, namely:

- [How to Repair a Broken Raspberry Pi SD Card Slot](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Repair-a-Broken-Raspberry-Pi-SD-Card-Slot/)
- [Raspberry Pi 3B+ boot from USB SSD or HDD external drive](https://lamiacasaelettrica.com/raspberry-pi-3-hard-disk-esterno/)

And I found a number of photographs showing "piece of electronics" with full sized SD card:

[image]

[image]

I was wondering, if there is any RPi-marked equipment (since both authors of both articles talks about RPi) that uses full-sized SD card? Or is this just an misunderstanding / misinterpretation on my side (or wrong picture used to depict blog post) and these images are in fact *not* showing any Raspberry Pi model.

If these are no RPi, can anyone by any chance figure out what kind of "electronics" it is that is using full-sized SD cards?

Comment: *Mais non*, @SteveRobillard -- the first one with a micro SD card model wise is the 1A/B **+** (I just learned this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the original model 1B (initially just "the model B") -- yes, they used a full size SD card.

I was not aware (or possibly, had forgotten) that the "final revision" of the 1B is the 1B+, which uses a micro SD card amongst other improvements (eg., the current 40 pin GPIO header, vs. the 26 pin on the original).

These differences are [detailed on the Rpi .com site](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-1-model-b-plus/) (under "Specifications"). This is sort of good news for me as I am keeping my 1Bs, which presumably aren't being made anymore, packed with anti-static bubble wrap in a remote freezer in hopes they will be worth big bucks by the time I retire ;)

Comment: By your freezer you just mean outside the back door right?

Comment: This leads me to a question, if it is possible to get 1B (for full-sized SD card) anywhere in the world (except your freezer)? The answer probably is: "no". Even "the Foundation" [says](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-1-model-b-plus/?resellerType=education) that it was replaced in 2014 and [doesn't have it in its stock list](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/).

Comment: I can't imagine that there is, especially after the past year or so of exorbitant supply-chain-woes pi pricing.  @SteveRobillard Actually it is a nanofridge I keep in a safe deposit box -- just have to go check it and replace the batteries every 6 weeks.

Comment: Last time I visited OfficeWorks I noticed they were still selling full size SD Cards. Never used one with a Pi - I have about 20 SD Card adapters.  On my model B on the odd occasions I power it up I use a micro adapter which mounts sideways on the Pi and doesn't hang out past the board. This used to be a common source of failure.

Comment: NOTE there NEVER was a **1B or 1B+** this is an anachronism. The **Raspberry Pi Model B** was released 29th Feb 2012, upgraded to [512MB](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/model-b-now-ships-with-512mb-of-ram/) on  15th Oct 2012 and [Raspberry Pi Model B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-raspberry-pi-model-b-plus/) released on 14th Jul 2014

Comment: I think you are right that they did not start doing this until the 2 came out, and it perhaps was just a colloquialism for a long time, but currently on the .com site they are sold by the manufacturer as "1B+" and "1A+" (the former described as having "replaced the Model B in July 2014").